# How to change the marker in a plot

Tags: matlab, plot, octave, matlab-figure

my question is about this code:

```
w = linspace(-5,5,1000);
figure
for alpha = -1:0.2:1
    delay = (alpha.*cos(w)-alpha^2)./(1-2*alpha.*cos(w)+alpha^2);
    plot(w,delay)
    hold on
end
grid on
xlabel('$\omega$', 'interpreter', 'latex')
```

I'd like to know if it's possible to change the type of the graphic in each iteration. For example, once with circles ('o-'), another with diamons ('d-'), etc.

Thanks for your responses.

Comment: I guess a possible solution is to have a cell array of the options you want, like `opt={'d-','o-'}` and then just using `opt{index}`

Comment: No, that gives me the error "Invalid first data argument"

Comment: Well, depends on how you code it, but you need to show it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
w = linspace(-5,5,1000);
alpha = -1:0.2:1;
shapes = '+o*.xsd^v><ph';
figure, hold on
for ii=1:numel(alpha)
    delay = (alpha(ii).*cos(w)-alpha(ii)^2)./(1-2*alpha(ii).*cos(w)+alpha(ii)^2);
    plot(w,delay,[shapes(ii),'-'])
end
grid on
xlabel('$\omega$', 'interpreter', 'latex')
```

In this plot, the points are so close together that you can't really make up the shapes. You can reduce the number of markers by plotting first the line without markers, then a subsampled version using only markers:

```
w = linspace(-5,5,1000);
alpha = -1:0.2:1;
figure, hold on
shapes = '+o*.xsd^v><ph';
cols = jet(numel(alpha));
for ii=1:numel(alpha)
    delay = (alpha(ii).*cos(w)-alpha(ii)^2)./(1-2*alpha(ii).*cos(w)+alpha(ii)^2);
    plot(w,delay,'-','color',cols(ii,:))
    plot(w(1:50:end),delay(1:50:end),shapes(ii),'color',cols(ii,:))
end
grid on
xlabel('$\omega$', 'interpreter', 'latex')
```

[image: output of code above, a graph as described]

If the number of lines is larger than the number of available markers, the code above will throw an indexing error. You can cycle through the markers instead by using `mod`. Replace `shapes(ii)` with

```
shapes(mod(ii-1,numel(shapes))+1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The only thing is that if I want each line with a different color, the shape doesn't have the same color of its line, but I solved that with (inside the for):
    p = plot(w,delay);
    plot(w(1:50:end),delay(1:50:end),'color',p.Color);

Comment: @Josemi: yes, that's one good way to do it. I've modified the post to show a different way, explicitly choosing the color for each line.